# How is divergence theorem used in this proof

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, finite-volume-method

[image]

I am studying conservation laws, i was doing the proof for the rankine hugoniot condition, in the middle of the proof they have used divergence theorem , but I do not understand how they have used that. There is no triple integral work, so how can they use divergence theorem ?

I have added the picture of the proof and highlited the part where the author has used divergence theorem.

Edit : now that I got the solution I don't understand this step. How to get this step

[image]

Comment: Please [use $\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to include the relevant equation, rather than a large screenshot. There is a 2-dimensional version of the divergence theorem; you need to combine it with the product rule to "integrate by parts".

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to realise $v_t$ and $v_x$ as the divergence of certain functions. Let $\nabla = (\partial_x, \partial_t)$ be the differential operator. Then 
\begin{align*}
\iint_{\Omega^-} uv_t\, dxdt & = \iint_{\Omega^-}u\nabla\cdot(v,0)\, dxdt \\
& = \int_{\partial\Omega^-} u(v,0)\cdot\underline{n}\, ds - \iint_{\Omega^-} (\nabla u)\cdot(v,0)\, dxdt.
\end{align*}
Now, $\partial\Omega^-$ consists of the $x$-axis and the curve $x=\xi(t)$, but there is no contribution of the first integral over the $x$-axis since $v(x,0) = 0$ by assumption. With $\underline{n} = (\nu_1,\nu_2)$, we then have
\begin{align*}
\iint_{\Omega^-} uv_t\, dxdt & = \int_{x=\xi(t)} u^-(v,0)\cdot(\nu_1,\nu_2)\, ds - \iint_{\Omega^-} (u_t, u_x)\cdot(v,0)\, dxdt \\
& = \int_{x=\xi(t)} u^-v\nu_1\, ds - \iint_{\Omega^-} u_tv\, dxdt. 
\end{align*}
You can apply the same argument to the other integral 
$$ \iint_{\Omega^-} f(u)v_x\, dxdt $$
and I will leave this as an exercise for you.

Comment: If you're not comfortable finishing the argument, let me know and I can add them to my answer (:

Comment: I am thankful to you for this. I will try the remaining part by myself, if I am not able to proceed, I will let you know

Comment: I have edited the question, i have a doubt about one step, please solve my doubt

Comment: @AbhishekChandra That is essentially the divergence theorem for functions of two-variables. You should think about it as the generalisation of the 1D integration by parts! See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Higher_dimensions for details.